# Extracting specific columns from multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, slice, dimensions

Suppose we have a 3d numpy array in Python of shape (1, 22, 22) -random dimensions for illustration. If i want to extract the first 2 dimensions from Y, Z, then I can do:

```
new_array = array[:, 0:2, 0:2] 
new_array.shape
(1, 2, 2)
```

But when I try to do the same by explicitly specifying the first two dimensions, as:

```
new_array = array[:, [0,1], [0,1]] 
new_array.shape
(1, 2)
```

I'm getting a different result. Why's that? How can I select specific dimensions and and not a range of dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a list to a numpy array's `__getite__` uses advanced indexing instead of slicing.  See the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a non-tuple sequence object, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool), or a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer and Boolean.

In your case, you are using the integer array indexing.  The chain of integer indices are broadcast and iterated as a single unit.  So using

```
array[:, [0,1], [0,1]]
```

selects elements `(0,0)` and `(1,1)`, *not* the zeroth and first subarray from dimension 1 and the zeroth and first subarray form dimension 2.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand my mistake but I still do not get after reading the documentation how to perform the operation.

Comment: basically, when you pass multiple lists of indices at multiple dimensions, the lists are `zip`ed together and the elements at those locations are extracted.

Comment: I understood the problem, but I find the documentation lacking from examples, so I don't understand how to solve my problem. I'm trying to use np._ix but can't get anywhere.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: A similar one to the aforementioned example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation and played around with my code. The only thing that seemed to work -but doesn't- with respect to my question is:

```
columns = np.array(([0, 1]), ([0,1]), dtype=np.intp)
new_array = my_array[:, columns, 0]
```

I'm still not quite sure why it works though.

EDIT: doesn't work as expected